# Calculating the duration of an event

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem. I have a list that is full of events (note: the list does not have to be sorted by date and can contain multiple IDs).
I would like to "know" how long an event lasted.
The calculation can be represented as follows

```
Duration of Event1 = Take the ID(Timestamp Event 2 - Timestamp Event 1)
```

For example:

```
Cleaning = ID1234 ( 06.11.2023 14:29- 06.11.2023 14:19) = 10 min
```

`End of Work` refers to the end, this should not be measured. I have tried it, but it counts incorrectly. So how can I improve it so that I get the desired output?

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'Timestamp': ['06.11.2023 14:19', '06.11.2023 14:29', '06.11.2023 14:37', '06.11.2023 14:41', '06.11.2023 15:00'],
    'Event Date': ['06.11.2023', '06.11.2023', '06.11.2023', '06.11.2023', '06.11.2023'],
    'ID': ['1234', '1234', '1234', '1234', '1234'],
    'Event Category': ['Working Event', 'Working Event', 'Working Event', 'Failure Event', 'Working Event'],
    'What did you do?': ['Cleaning', 'Recording', 'Insert', pd.NA, 'End of Work']
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

df = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'Event Category', 'Timestamp'])

df['Duration'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'Event Category'])['Timestamp'].diff().dt.seconds.div(60, fill_value=0)

print(df)
```

Dataframe

```py
          Timestamp  Event Date    ID Event Category What did you do?
0  06.11.2023 14:19  06.11.2023  1234  Working Event         Cleaning
1  06.11.2023 14:29  06.11.2023  1234  Working Event        Recording
2  06.11.2023 14:37  06.11.2023  1234  Working Event           Insert
3  06.11.2023 14:41  06.11.2023  1234  Failure Event             <NA>
4  06.11.2023 15:00  06.11.2023  1234  Working Event      End of Work
```

What I have

```py
[OUT]
Timestamp  Event Date    ID Event Category What did you do?  \
3 2023-11-06 14:41:00  06.11.2023  1234  Failure Event             <NA>   
0 2023-11-06 14:19:00  06.11.2023  1234  Working Event         Cleaning   
1 2023-11-06 14:29:00  06.11.2023  1234  Working Event        Recording   
2 2023-11-06 14:37:00  06.11.2023  1234  Working Event           Insert   
4 2023-11-06 15:00:00  06.11.2023  1234  Working Event      End of Work   

   Duration  
3       0.0  
0       0.0  
1      10.0  
2       8.0  
4      23.0
```

What I want

```py
          Timestamp  Event Date    ID Event Category What did you do?   Duration
0  06.11.2023 14:19  06.11.2023  1234  Working Event         Cleaning   10
1  06.11.2023 14:29  06.11.2023  1234  Working Event        Recording   8
2  06.11.2023 14:37  06.11.2023  1234  Working Event           Insert   4
3  06.11.2023 14:41  06.11.2023  1234  Failure Event             <NA>   19
4  06.11.2023 15:00  06.11.2023  1234  Working Event      End of Work   -
```

Comment: Why are you not sorting by timestamp first?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend re-organizing the dataset a little bit such that it is more convenient to handle duration calculation.

Firstly, sort only by timestamp, such that you get timeline of the events.
Now you can create new feature "End event" by taking the start of the next event.

After that the calculation of the Duration is trivial.

Here are my adjustments:

```
import pandas as pd
# Import numpy for roll function
import numpy as np

data = {
    'Timestamp': ['06.11.2023 14:19', '06.11.2023 14:29', '06.11.2023 14:37', '06.11.2023 14:41', '06.11.2023 15:00'],
    'Event Date': ['06.11.2023', '06.11.2023', '06.11.2023', '06.11.2023', '06.11.2023'],
    'ID': ['1234', '1234', '1234', '1234', '1234'],
    'Event Category': ['Working Event', 'Working Event', 'Working Event', 'Failure Event', 'Working Event'],
    'What did you do?': ['Cleaning', 'Recording', 'Insert', pd.NA, 'End of Work']
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

# Sort only by timestamp
df = df.sort_values('Timestamp')

# Rename
df = df.rename(columns={"Timestamp": "Start event"})

# Calculate the end event by taking the start of the next event
df["End event"] = np.roll(df["Start event"], -1)
# Roll function also rolls over the end/start of the list
# so we have to remove it
df.loc[df.index[-1], "End event"] = np.nan

# Now calculating duration is easy
df["Duration"] = df["End event"] - df["Start event"]

# Groupby whatever and calculate whatever metric
df.groupby("What did you do?")["Duration"].mean()
```

The output will be

```
What did you do?
Cleaning      0 days 00:10:00
End of Work               NaT
Insert        0 days 00:04:00
Recording     0 days 00:08:00
Name: Duration, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Feel free to convert it to seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure if grouping is needed here, as far as I understand, one line, one event or how the event is identified (if the event is: Event Category, then all Working Event rows must be one event)?

The same result is obtained:

```
df['Duration'] = df['Timestamp'].diff().dt.seconds.div(60, fill_value=0).shift(-1)
```

Output:

```
            Timestamp  Event Date    ID Event Category What did you do?  Duration
0 2023-11-06 14:19:00  06.11.2023  1234  Working Event         Cleaning      10.0
1 2023-11-06 14:29:00  06.11.2023  1234  Working Event        Recording       8.0
2 2023-11-06 14:37:00  06.11.2023  1234  Working Event           Insert       4.0
3 2023-11-06 14:41:00  06.11.2023  1234  Failure Event             <NA>      19.0
4 2023-11-06 15:00:00  06.11.2023  1234  Working Event      End of Work       NaN
```